# Ion charge exchange mean free path

Tags: plasma-physics, mean-free-path

I am using the following equation to calculate the mean free path between a deuteron ion and background gas:
$$\lambda_{d-gas} = \frac{kT_{gas}}{p_{gas} \, \sigma_{10}}$$
Where $\sigma_{10}$ is the charge exchange cross-section at a given ion energy. $T_{gas}$ and $p_{gas}$ are the temperature and pressure of the background gas, respectively, and $k$ is Boltzmann's constant.

The deuteron's energy varies with time and since the ion's energy strongly effects the charge exchange cross-section I want to be able to account for this change in the calculation of mean free path. How would I do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you elaborate on how the deuteron's energy varies with time? What's the mechanism that changes it?

Comment: @lemon, it is being accelerated and decelerated by an electric field.

Comment: Well I can't imagine any external field changes rapidly enough that the deuteron's energy changes significantly *between* collisions. In which case, the mean free path is give by the equation you provide but where $\sigma_{10}$ is evaluated as a function of the deuteron's energy at the present moment in time...

Comment: @lemon, the electric field isn't changing, but the proximity of the ion to the electrodes is, which rapidly changes its velocity and thus it happens on a time scale shorter than collisions.

Comment: Heather, I don't know scattering amplitude calculations from a hole in the ground, so apologies.  Although the electric field itself is  not changing,  for the **ion** the field strength is oscillating as it changes position, is that a correct assumption? If I am way off track, please ignore this. Just a yes or no will do, I am trying to think this through on my own.

Comment: @CountTo10, the field strength is changing for the ion as its position relative to the electrode changes. So it isn't really a yes or a no.

Comment: Please tell me if this is in the same ball park of what you are asking?http://www.teramobile.org/teramobile.html